# Form data posted twice? PHP function runs twice?

Tags: javascript, php

I've got a `register` and `register.inc` file. When a user hits the register button, an `onclick` triggers a function in an external `js` file.
The form is posted to the `register` file I mentioned earlier. This file has the `register.inc` file included. The `register` file looks like this:

```
<?
require_once "register.php";

if (!empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['p']) && !empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $register = new Register();
    $register -> set("email", $_POST['email']);
    $register -> set("password", $_POST['p']);
    $register -> set("name", $_POST['name']);
    $register -> set("recaptcha", $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    $register -> register();
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that the `register()` function is being executed twice. I've tested it with `error_log()` which appears twice every single time.

There are no extra click events being added to the signup button and there are no empty `href` or `src` tags in my markup that some other pages suggested might be the problem.

I have been trying to solve this problem for hours now and have found no way of solving it.

Thanks

Comment: Let echo 'some things'; at register and use `Firebug` or something see Response.

Comment: It's not the register file that executes twice, it's the register.inc that executes twice.

Comment: Well maybe its when the form is submitted... the page refreshes and submits again. Why don't you have `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {`?

Comment: I don't have that `$_POST['submit']` because I'm not using a submit input. I am sending hashing the password by using a JS function which submits the form with all the values when it has finished processing them.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that nothing in either my `register` or `register.inc` can cause the data to be posted twice...

Comment: It seems that onclick set 2 times